# HTML + CSS trying to use <code> or <xmp> to create line of text

Tags: html

I am trying to write guide like in codeacademy.
I want to write line with part of code and then white text.
i tried couple of methods, the text always go down line below the `<code>` or `<xmp>`

How can I create straight line with some code, for example red colored, then some text? I tried this:

```
<xmp style="color:#C34D57; "> <!DOCTYPE html> textextext </xmp>
```

and dozen more methods

Comment: Hi TheJoker, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you forget to finish your question(I'm guessing the textextext part was a placeholder?). Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried? It will be a lot easier for us to help you if you include code.

Comment: It was just example, i simply try to build straight line with colored code then paragraph, but it wont stay together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp), the `<xmp>` element is obsolete and should not be used. It goes on to say:

> Use the `<pre>` element or, if semantically adequate, the `<code>`
>   element instead. Note that you will need to escape the `'<'` character
>   as `'&lt;'` to make sure it is not interpreted as markup.

So you could use:

```
<pre>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; textextext </pre>
```

Example:

```css
pre {
  color: #C34D57;
}

span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<pre>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; <span>textextext</span> </pre>
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Comment: Great ! but now the text is the same color as the code part, i need the textextext to be black..

Comment: @TheJoker Then you'd need to wrap that part in a tag, like a `<span>`, but don't convert the `<` or `>`, and then create a CSS rule for it. E.g. `<pre>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; <span>textextext</span></pre>`